# Segmentation fault while opening a .txt file for writing

Tags: c, file, text, io, overriding

I am trying to `open` a `.txt` file in a specific `path` for **writing**.
I wan't to **override** the first `k` characters in the `.txt` file

```
Example:
File before overriding:
0123456789s

File after overriding:
tonytannous
```

However, I am getting a **segmentation fault**.
I am running on **windows7**, but I am compiling and running the code on a **VS** which OS is **linux**, using VMWare.

```
int func (int k, char* data, char* path)
{
    int fp;
    fp = open(path, O_RDWR);
    if (fp == -1)
        return -1;
    if (write (fp, data, k) != k)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char data[10] = "tonytannou";
    char path[1000];
    int k = 3;
    scanf("%s", &path);
    return func(k, data, path);
}
```

I made sure the path was spelled right, and file does exist there.
Any idea why such a thing might be happening ?

**EDIT:** used `perror()` and the error is **ILLEGAL SEEK**
I am now even more confused.

Comment: First problem: `char data[10] = /* 11 character string when 0 terminator counted */`

Comment: @John3136 that is not the problem.

Comment: @John3136 I used perror() to find what went wrong, it says illegal seek.
Any idea what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "&" operator on "path" array in scanf

In C, the name of array itself is a pointer(In this case, "path" is the pointer of path array), you don't need to get its address by "&" operator and pass it to scanf.

You can use debug tool to check what value is storing in "path" array after scanf is done.

Comment: If changing "&path" to "path" can't solve your problem. Maybe you should run gdb for test.
gdb will stop immediately while segmentation fault occurs and print out where the segmentation fault occurs.
BTW, this code runs well on my Linux environment after deleting "&"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `scanf("%s", &path);`. Rewrite it to `scanf("%s", path);` or `scanf("%s", &path[0]);`, because `path` is already pointer to the start (first element) of the array.